# Coordinate transformation of a table of multi-variable function values

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, coordinate-transformation

I've created a table in Mathematica for a function dependent on `r` and `phi` of the form

```
data = Table[f, {phi, 0, 2*Pi, 0.5}, {r, 0., 20*10^-6, 0.5*10^-6}]
```

Now I'd like to plot this data in a 3D plot, however, to my knowledge I'd have to transform the data into Cartesian coordinates first since Mathematica doesn't provide a straight forward way to plot functions dependent on multiple spherical coordinates (?).

I don't know which is the best way to do so, since I'm new to Mathematica and don't really understand the syntax yet so I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Maybe SphericalPlot3D would help?

Comment: It would helpful if you told us how `f` is defined.